# Stuck on project without answer

Tags: discussion

I'm a student and I usually ask here when I don't find an answer after long time researching.

I have a problem in one of my projects and I've been stuck on it for a couple of weeks now. I asked a question 4 or 5 day ago and didn't get an answer and I don't have enough reputation to put a bounty on the question. What should I do?

Comment: Typically when questions go unanswered it's because they're either overly specific to the asker's scenario and other users can't relate -OR- the question is not written in a way to properly convey the problem -OR- there's not enough information to determine what the issue is.  Fortunately, if you're able to rewrite the question and provide a minimal, reproducible example, this is the best way to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Matthew so when the problem is specific i cant do anything ?

Comment: @MrFlick sorry i didnt know

Comment: If you are a student doing an assignment, then there should also be a supervisor who can help you with it. I also couldn't find a question of yours which were asked in the last week and didn't receive an answer.

Comment: Did you apply appropriate tags? Tags are what guide people to your question.

Comment: You likely received feedback about your specific question. I'd be surprised if someone didn't at least comment to say, "You're approaching this completely wrong; try this other approach instead." Or they asked questions to clarify whether that might be the case. If you received those kinds of comments, pay attention to them.

Comment: As a student, one of the key skills you'll want to establish is that of proofreading. In this meta post, there were many spelling and grammar errors. Some of that could be discounted by English not being a native language, and that's fine, but you're on an English-only site used by and for professionals. Something to consider. Sure, there people who will edit your question (here on meta, and on main) to clean it up, but as you transition from school to professional environments, I think it behooves you to learn as best you can from those edits.

Comment: @BDL It was the mongo problem I got and the problem was so stupid when I found it. Also sorry again for my english I'm trying my best to be understable, for the most part I´ve learned by myself to speak english. I´m also fully aware that you guyz also have work and Im thankfull for all the informations that I can get from all of you.

Answer (score 7):

Be patient.

We're all volunteers, working our normal jobs, dealing with other circumstances, and we don't always have time to answer every individual question.

We're not very suitable for quick responses to individual questions, so the expectation I'll set here for you is that if you're stuck on something *and* you need immediate help, then you should reach out to a resource which can give you immediate feedback, such as your professor, a tutor or a classmate.  Stack Overflow will give *eventual* feedback.

Comment: Sorry I know that the problem is that we have student startup that do not have teacher assigned so I was stuck by myself and the problem I got was to hard to figure out by my classmate to and I didnt find solution on internet so I didnt knew where I could find more information.